# Blackberry - How to retrieve images from a zip resource file?

Tags: image, blackberry, resources, compression

I am using eclipse & JDE to develop Blackberry Application. I compressed a folder which has set of images in .jpg and .png formats. Please help me, how to retrieve images form the zipped file?

Thank you.....

Comment: in what format you compressed a folder? As far as I know there is no multiple compression in gzip neither in zlib. and that is two only compression formats blackberry platform supports.

Comment: as coldice stated, it's typically a waste of time to compress an already compressed file format, you're not saving an appreciable amount of space for the processing overhead...don't bother, just put all your images in the img folder and load them as resources...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see any reason to compress compressed graphic format. Anyway it can't be efficient. It's better to add all images to progect img folder and use them as a resources from code:

```
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("image.png");
```